# DiffUtils and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my adapter, when i'm changing something, from api. But when i'm getting a new array from api and trying `dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)` my adapter position is gettin 0 like if i'm going to `notifyDataSetChanged()` . How can i stay on my current position after updating array from api?

my DiffCallback:

```
public class EventListDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    private List<Event> newList;
    private List<Event> oldList;

    public EventListDiffCallback(List<Event> old, List<Event> newList){
        this.oldList = old;
        this.newList = newList;
    }


    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return oldList!=null ? oldList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return newList != null ? newList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).getId() == newList.get(newItemPosition).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldList.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newList.get(newItemPosition));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {

        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}
```

How i'm updating values in adapter:

```
public void setNewData(List<Event> newData) {
    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new EventListDiffCallback(this.data, newData), true);
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(newData);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

Comment: are ids stable in your api call? i mean `getId()` method, does it return the same id for the same item?

Comment: Yes, everything is stable, 
except value `inWishList`

Comment: ok so for testing call `dispatchUpdatesTo(ListUpdateCallback updateCallback)` method and add `Log.d` inside every `on*` method, what do you see on the logcat? you should see only `onChanged` method to be called if your new data contains only updated items

Comment: @pskink What exactly i need to log, positions and counts of ListCallback?

Comment: first try just `position`s - i dont think `onMoved` will be called ;-)

Comment: @pskink i'm getting onChanged position= 0, payload = null, what does this mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164078/discussion-between-toper-and-pskink).

Comment: try [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/mYKWRDxw) adapter - in one word: `areContentsTheSame` is broken (or `Event#equals` method)

Comment: @pskink i think i have problem in my DiscreteScrollView infinite scroll adapter

Comment: did you try the sample adapter i posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (list>0) {
      list.setSelectionFromTop(yourLastPosition, 0);
 }
```

`yourLastPosition` this is your integer value , you can get this with implementing onScroll .